# Anchor image to position and stop re-scaling. Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview

I designed two separate images "background" and "circle". They fit almost perfectly into each other.(See image below). After displaying them in android studio using kotlin their dimensions (Android Studio Design Window) and position (On the actual phone screen) are somehow altered and they dont fit into each other anymore.

[image]

Please, how can I stop this?

myCode and images:

https://gist.github.com/svenbioinf/1fc1e81f5f3325e266b139b7e7f9d603

https://i.ibb.co/mBFvS5f/circle.png

https://i.ibb.co/DLqyq09/background.png

Comment: you can use `constraint layout` and overlap the foreground image over background image. And when you set constraints like this.. on each device the output will be the same. Kindly let me know if you need any help.